# how can i transpose pitches from a minor key to another minor key?

Tags: transposition

I am looking to transpose a melody from e minor to f minor. Is there any easier way to do it other than looking at the degree of each note and matching it to the wanted key? Also, how to I transpose notes with accidentals?

I have pasted a link for reference to the melody.

https://scontent.fybz2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/s2048x2048/78834207_565664434265410_5193439772462284800_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=ZcKiWPmmHyQAQkpioMyBPaDQupMrBss63okvqJ3QjTf9lxFKHDcyP6QWw&_nc_ht=scontent.fybz2-2.fna&oh=042f2bea1efab0ed41566f688224c068&oe=5E498344

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this wasn't your homework! Maybe I should've put a deliberate mistake in it. In fact maybe I did!

[image: In Fm]

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather approach that transposition task this way: determine the interval between the tonic of the new key and the tonic of the old key, then move all the notes by that interval. In this case, we need to transpose from E Minor to F Minor, so we need to move all the notes up one semitone.

Correct enharmonic spellings of notes with accidentals (and, occasionally, those without) as you go along. Other than that, treat notes with accidentals the exact same way as those without.